# Limit by month rather than all results

Tags: sql, hive

I know that to get random 1000 records I can do something like this:

```
select a, b, month, avg(c) as c
from
(select bla bla --string parsing and other data cleanup
from table) t
group by a, b, month
order by rand()
limit 1000
```

However, this will give a total of 1000 records.

What I would like to get is 1000 random records for each month (since table is just way to big). If it is possible, can you help re-write the above?

Note that this is a Hive question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by month order by random()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where sequm <= 1000;
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is this going to give me 1000 records x # months (ie. if 12 months then 12K records) or 1000 records total? Because I need it at 1000 for each month.

Comment: This will provide 1000 records for each month.  That is how the `partition by` works.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!